# How to map a UID to another UID (!= 0) inside a user namespace?

Tags: lxc, userns

How can one map UID 1000 to another regular UID (not root/0) inside a user namespace?

EDIT: For anyone interested, https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html lists an option `lxc.init_uid` which seems to be related to this but is not recognized by my version of LXC. If anyone manages to get this to work please let me know.